# Strange NTC behaviour: it goes open circuit when cooling down

Tags: thermistor, failure-mode

My partner has a heater for heating wax that is used for waxing legs and other body parts. She told me it stopped working; it does not heat up anymore.

When I opened the device and looked at it I found that the temperature is controlled by an NTC. When I measured its value, my meter said that it is open-circuit.

However, when I heat the NTC with a hot air gun, its resistance drops to a few kOhm.

When I let it cool down, its resistance increases and when it reaches 32 kOhm, it suddenly goes open-circuit.

I've repeated the heating and cooling cycle a few times to make sure that it isn't a fluke (although I am using a Fluke multimeter).

I've never seen an NTC behave like this; the resistance normally increases until it reaches its nominal value at room temperature.

Is this a special NTC or is it just broken?

I haven't been able to look at the NTC itself, because it is built into the device and I don't want to take it further apart unless I am pretty confident that the NTC is broken and needs replacing.

The NTC is soldered to two leads and is inside heat-shrink. The assembly is wrapped in transparent light-brown-yellowish adhesive tape. I assume that this is heat-resistant adhesive tape.

Comment: +1 for the fluke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite common behavior of **NTC**s, i.e. **N**egative **T**emperature **C**oefficient thermistors: probably the device you've at hand is designed to work at high temperatures, therefore its resistance is very high at ambient temperatures, so high that for a normal tester it resembles an open circuit (for example \$\ge 10\mathrm{M}\Omega\$). Here it is a typical resistance vs. temperature behavior diagram taken from the [Wikipedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NTC_Thermistor_RT_Characteristic1.svg):

[image]

The vertical asymptote can start even at \$25°\mathrm{C}\$, making the increase of resistance at low temperature very steep.